# Windows 10 usb camera not working from code but works from other programs

Tags: c#, python, c++, windows-10, webcam

I am unable to create an application in any programming language that will playback video from a usb webcam.

I want to display video feed from a webcam, and then take a snapshot of a frame at the press of a button.

The existing program uses avicap32.dll and works fine on older versions of windows, but does not work on windows 10.

On windows 10 I tested that VLC is able to playback the webcam from dshow, and it is able too. I then made a c# application that used a libvlc wrapper to play the webcam, and no video is ever loaded. However the light on my webcam lights up while the app is running. If i take the application and move the webcam to a windows 7 pc video plays in my c# app.

I then tried ffmpeg, running ffplay from command line plays video from webcam no problem. I made a c# app that will create a new process and run the ffplay exe with arguments. I get an error in the ffplay output saying it could not find the video format.

I then tried running ffplay from a subprocess in python, basicaly the exact same thing as the c# app above. This time video playback is successful.

I figured it must be something to do with c#. So I made a quick c++ application that uses lib vlc to play dshow://. I get no video playback but the light on the webcam turns on. If i move this c++ application to the windows 7 machine the application works and displays video from the camera. (this was made using mingw and not visual c++)

I also attempted to use directshow but that also did not work. just got a black image, and was unable to copy frames.

The strange thing is I was able to use the Universal app c# examples from microsoft and it is able to use the webcam. I have to give the example application permission to use the webcam first.

Furthermore, I know the webcam is working fine on the windows 10 machine because the Camera app in windows 10 works fine, vlc works fine, and ffplay work fine.

Does anyone know what is going on here? Is microsoft playing games? Are they forcing people to use univeral apps if they want webcam access? How is VLC, FFMPEG. working they'r not universal apps.

Update:
I'v still had no luck getting a winforms application to display an image from the webcam, however, I decided to use Process to start my python script that starts ffplay, and suprisingly I got the same error message i got when just directly running ffplay from c# using process. The error im getting is 
"Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, dshow, from 'video=Logitech HD Webcam C615':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc"

UPDATE 2:

I'm surprised of how little information online is available on this topic. However for those of you in the future that face this problem. I found a article on the Microsoft website, that states that the new app security mechanism in windows 10 version 1809 prevents any application from accessing camera's and microphones unless they are UWP, and have permissions. However, if the application knows how to directly communicate with the device bypassing windows libraries it is possible for that application to still use the camera. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4468234
This is where I ended, I am going to make a UWP app with a tcp socket server to broker webcam images to my old software.

Comment: Have you tried opencv if you're interested with frames only? Have not tried it with audio

Comment: I did not try OpenCV but did look into it. the installation is 1.2GB and it uses directshow. I suspect OpenCV would not work just the same as the other libraries I tried. While I wait ill give OpenCV a try.

Comment: I just tried OpenCV using a wrapper myEmguCV.Net in c#. I am getting the same behavior blank image on screen, light on camera turns on. I also tested the same app on windows 7 and it works fine.

Comment: Thats weird indeed, and the camera windows 10 app works?

Comment: yes the built in windows 10 app works fine with the camera.